# Why is my sphere jumping?

Tags: unity

I got a sphere that moves with an angular velocity of -2000 in the X axis, I need that sphere moves on 130 platforms, all those platforms have -0.0182175 in the Y axis.

The problem is that when I play, the sphere starts normally but as it advances starts make some jumps, first shorts but then more large, and it is as if the platforms did not have the same value in the Y axis.

Can someone help me, please?

I've put some images.

[image: Y-Axis and all the 130 platforms]

Very thanks

Hey people!!
I've uploaded a video to show you clearly the problem.

Here's the link: [Platforms, sphere and sphere script](https://youtu.be/RU6g_zEajFg)

Sorry for my english by the way.

Comment: Can we see your code?

Comment: Would also help to include your ball object or even just the collider it has.

Answer (score 1):

There is some considerations: 

First, why the y is such uncertain value? It's better to set y to a certain value like 0 or 1.

Second, maybe the y of all platforms are equal, but they haven't aligned correctly beside each other.use v key on the keyboard to snap each platform to another one.

Third, maybe platform colliders are not match exactly with sprites.
In the collider component, Click on edit to see the shape of colliders.

And finally, check if jumps occur with some specific sprites or it occur randomly.
Hopr it helps.

Comment: Upvote to this answer , reason 1 : he use uncertain value because he can do that ( -1 ) , reason 2 : aggree , not aligned correctly ( +1 ) , reason 3 : aggree about the non-match colliders ( +1 ) , reason 4 : aggree about occur randomly ( +1 ) , 1+1+1-1 = +3 for this answer .